# Convert character to correct ASCII-extended integer value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Code below contains a JS function that receives as parameter String "€€" (Euro sign).
I need to convert each one of these characters to its ASCII-extended integer equivalent (128 with ISO-8859-1).

However, t[0] and t[1] take value "8364" instead of "128". What am I doing wrong? Please note that if I use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1, they take value 65533 and in the JS debugger (Chrome and IE developer tools) a question mark is displayed instead of € symbol.

Thanks a mil

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JavaScript Scripting</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1">
function d(s) 
{
    var data = (s + "").split("");
    var dataLength = data.length;
    var t = [dataLength],n;

    for(n=0;n<dataLength;n++)
    t[n]=data[n].charCodeAt(0);
}
d("€€");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Full story is that I pasted this "€€" from file "output.js", where these two bytes were written by Java code below, representing integers [128,128]. That is why I need t[0] and t[1] to get value 128.

```
res.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); 
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=output.js;charset=ISO-8859-1");
ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
char result[]=encode(req.getParameter("originalScript"));
// result[0] and result[1] have here integer value 128
String result2=new String(result);
// result2 is displayed here as non printable characters (blank)
os.print(result2);
// On output.js "€€" is displayed
```

Comment: € in ASCII? Is there such a beast?

Comment: There is no `€` in ISO-8859-1.  Did you mean windows-1252?

Comment: I have updated issue description. I intended to create file with ISO-8859-1, but perhaps code above is wrong for this purpose. Can you please assist? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the file is actually saved as ISO-8859-1, but that is actually not possible as there is no € character in that character set.

> "ISO/IEC 8859-1 is missing [...] the euro sign."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

As you are getting the character code 8364, the file is most likely saved as UTF-8, as that character code corresponds with the [unicode character €](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems to be the origin of the problem. I have updated issue description. I intended to create file with ISO-8859-1, but perhaps code above is wrong for this purpose. Can you please assist? Thanks

Comment: @user411103: You are using some non-standard form of ISO-8859-1, as the standard version doesn't have any characers for codes 128 to 159. Anyway, when you copy the text from the file it's just text, it doesn't have any encoding information. When you paste the text and save it, it will be encoded with whatever encoding the program is using. You should specify the encoding when you save the file (e.g. using Save As... option).

Comment: I will need to write integers from 0-255 in one printable character. What charset would you recommend me? Thanks

Comment: Why not ``UTF-8``? All browsers support it, it's easily manipulated by Javascript (which uses a different UTF format internally but can easily cross between the two representations), and the whole point of UTF was to have a single character coding that can handle *every character mankind has ever invented.* UTF-8 does so in such a way that representations of Western characters requires very little space and remain mostly compatible with ASCII. (I believe 7-bit ASCII is a subset?)

Comment: @user411103: There is no common character set that works that way. If you need to send data like that, you shouldn't treat it as text at all.

Comment: I just tried with UTF-8 and character 128 was showing from Chrome or IE Javascript debuggers as �???

Comment: Thanks Guffa. Should I change the type=text/javascript for application/octet-stream everywhere?

Comment: I just tried changing "type=text/javascript" to "application/octet-stream" at the Content-Type headers, but it is still not working. Javascript debuggers show error when find character �

Comment: @user411103: You can't include text as non-text. You simply can't add data that way to a web page.

Comment: If I write this data in a webpage textarea instead of a separate file, it works. The problem is only when I write this data in a file and try to read from it later.

Comment: @user411103: The problem is that there is no way to transport the file content directly to the client script without transforming it so that it can be delivered as part of the HTML code, or as a separate request that can be parsed by the XHR object. Some characters work when you put them in a textarea, but far from the full 0 to 255 range.